# Tomcat web app url 8080 hidden

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have tomcat server running on 8080.
but access url www.mydomain.com:8080/myproject/  but i want to display
 url www.mydomain.com/myproject/ so how can do that....port 80 also have wamp running with different application

Answer (score 0):

Short: You cannot.

Long: If the web application runs on a port different than 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS), the browser will always show the port, as it is part of the URL. So you have to run your app on port 80/443. If the port 80 is already taken by Apache, you have to configure the Apache to map your app, e.g. in a virtual host. See https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html